# CSS3 background image fade effect

Tags: html, css

I want to swap background images with the fade **effect**, I tried this:

```
    -webkit-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    -moz-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    -o-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
```

and it **slides** instead of **fade**. What should I change?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean it "slides"?

Comment: the new background slides from bottom, I need the fade effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I also looked for this effect to do with CSS3 but find no luck! Will follow up your question. I solve this issue with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)! Lots of plugins are available. You can check [THIS](http://www.geeksucks.com/toolbox/23-jquery-fade-in-fade-out-effect.htm) page. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really, with a transition you say "if property-x changes, make sure it takes y seconds and use z animation, delay it with n"

So if you change the background-position, the background will slide to that position.
if you want it to fade you should use two different element and change the opacity of both